# Not getting any email confirmation mail from Area 51

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, email-verification

I was creating a proposal on Area 51 and i got a confirmation page, which says i need to confirm my email address. But i am not getting any mail. Checked my email address, Double checked my inbox, spam. Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last verification I can find to you in our echo account was sent July 24

```
reply-to      do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com
to            xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com
date          Sat, Jul 24, 2010 at 12:28 PM
subject       Email Verification - Area 51 - Stack Exchange
mailed-by     stackoverflow.com
signed-by     stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 1):

We just fixed a bug in which email verifications were sometimes not sent during proposal creation, so this shouldn't happen again.