# Cannot receive the verification email from Area 51

Tags: support, area-51, email-verification

It looks like a similar issue to *[Not getting any email confirmation mail from Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61053/not-getting-any-email-confirmation-mail-from-area-51)*.

I hit "re-send email verification to my_email_address" for a couple of times, but I didn't receive anything. Spam is also empty.

Comment: Are you getting any errors, e.g. as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312494/re-send-the-confirmation-email-link-not-working)? If not, can you check the browser's console and network tab for errors?

Comment: I didn't get any error in browser console, network request to send email was also 200. I see `email verification sent` after clicking it, but just cannot receive the email.

Comment: I tried creating a new account use another email, cannot receive verification email either.

Comment: ah I've seen something in the past about SE not "supporting" one time emails, so perhaps even not sending them those links. Can you try with gmail or other "main stream" provider, in case you're not using such already?

Comment: I tried using a gmail account and a hotmail account, both cannot receive the confirmation email. I can receive email from other stack exchange sites (meta, stack overflow, solana.stackexchange), just not from area 51

Comment: So sadly only a developer (of SE) can tell what's going on, and this... might take a while. However, what is your goal exactly? What you want to do in Area51?

Comment: I'm trying to propose a new site for aptos developer community (similar to https://solana.stackexchange.com/). I'm a software engineer at aptos labs, we are contributing to aptos blockchain (https://aptoslabs.com/).

Comment: That's fair, so all I can do is wish you good luck and sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks, Ill wait for a stack exchange developer to take a look